# React Native - unable to render the response from backend api without click

Tags: reactjs, native

I have a backend API, which when called , returns JSON, and stores data (not even 5 records, maximum 2 columns each)into a state variable inside React Native APP, which needs to be rendered on the APP screen. But somehow, it is not rendering without a CLICK in the simulator or else it takes more than 10s to render.

**NodeJS - API**

```
app.post('/getInvoicesWithoutToken', function (req, res) {
    var obj = req.body;
    let response = {};
    console.log("/getInvoicesWithoutToken"+new Date());
      let sql = "select * from invoices order by invoiceDate desc";
      console.log(sql);
      db.query(sql, function (err, row) {
        if(row) {
          response.code = "S";
          response.alert = "OFF";
          response.alertMessage = "SUCCESS";
          response.data = row;
          res.json(response);
        }
        else {
          response.code = "E";
          response.alert = "ON";
          response.alertMessage = "Error - Unable to find your invoices. Please try again";
          response.data = "";
          res.json(response);
        }
    });
  });
```

**React Native - backend.js**

```
export const getInvoicesWithoutToken = (obj) => {
  const URL = customData.apiURL+"/getInvoicesWithoutToken";
  return fetch(URL, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(obj),
 })
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });
}
```

**React Native - Screen code**

```
_getInvoicesWithoutToken = async () => {
    const obj = {};
    getInvoicesWithoutToken(obj)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.code === "S") {
  this.setState({ 
              showSpinner: false, 
              allInvoices : response.data
            });
      }  
    })
}

render() {
   let dataReceived = []; 
    dataReceived = this.state.allInvoices;
     let spinner = <Text></Text>;
    if(this.state.showSpinner)
    {
      spinner = <View style={{alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center'}}><Spinner color='blue' /><Text>Searching for invoices...</Text></View>
    }

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content>
        {spinner}
        <View>
            {
                dataReceived.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <View key={i} style={{padding:10,}}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>
                        {item.customerName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={styles.subTitle}>
                        {item.invoiceDate}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                )
                })
            }
        </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you use componentDidMount?

Comment: Yes.  ```componentDidMount(){
    this._getInvoicesWithoutToken();
 }```

Comment: Try to replace dataReceived with this.state.allInvoices and add a condition to check if it is not null. Also I would strongly suggest redux framework with saga. Makes things easier to handle rather than doing it on react state as it's async and unreliable at times.